# MySQL Full text search on multiple keywords one-many

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search, sql-like

I'm trying to use MySQL's FTS to search through indexed content to look for certain keywords. For what I'm trying to make, it needs either one or more of the keywords in the text, and the keywords must be exact word matches. However, it doesn't matter if the keywords is in the middle of another word, for example, when searching for "STACK", it should match:

1. Hi, I have a stack of overflows
2. Stacked against the wall
3. These bookcases are overstacked completely

I was using the following method before:

`SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE text LIKE '%keyword1%' OR LIKE '%keyword2%' OR LIKE '%keyword3%'`

This would return any text that would contain any of the keywords. However, this began to slow down pretty much everything, because most of the indexed content is big (stored in blob) and I have over 500 of those rows to index through. As Like is not using any indexing with this method, I tried converting to FTS using the following:

`SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE MATCH(text) AGAINST ('+keyword1 +keyword2 +keyword3' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

This worked good with single keywords, but when entering multiple keywords, this fails because FTS with the + operand NEEDS to find a match with the given words. But without these keywords, the FTS matches fuzzy results, not exact results. I end up with content being missed that most definitly contains the keywords.

What can I use to get all content that contain either one or more of the axact keywords?

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table MATCH (text) AGAINST ('+"keyword1" +"keyword2"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: This works the same as without "", it only finds text with all keywords, instead of either one of the keywords.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for something like the following:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... 
WHERE MATCH(text) AGAINST ('+keyword1' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
OR MATCH(text) AGAINST ('+keyword2' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
OR MATCH(text) AGAINST ('+keyword3' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```